# Define an Objective-C category function if not already defined

Tags: objective-c, ios8

iOS 8 introduced a `containsString` to `NSString` that checks whether the receiver contains a substring or not. It's less awkard than writing `[myString rangeOfString:@"substring"].location == NSNotFound`. I would like to write a category on `NSString` that defines `containsString` for iOS 7 and below. I have two conditions in defining it:

1. I do not want to take the cheap way out by naming my function `[customPrefix]ContainsString`. My goal is to avoid awkwardness and not have to think about two `containsString` functions.
2. I do not want to override iOS 8's implementation, because it may be written to run more efficiently than mine. It may also be upgraded in future iOS versions to handle new technologies (such as what happened when iOS 5 introduced ARC)

This is what I presume the code would resemble:

```
@implementation NSString (utility)

#if MAGIC_MACRO_CONTAINS_STRING_NOT_DEFINED
- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString*)substring 
{
    return [self rangeOfString:substring].location != NSNotFound;
}
#endif

@end
```

Comment: You could check in the runtime if the method exists using `respondsToSelector`, and if it doesn't, add the method to the class using the `objc_addMethod` method described in the [Objective-C runtime reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Give your category method your own unique name. Write it to call the new `containsString` if it exists or `rangeOfString` if it doesn't.

There's no way to conditionally implement a category method which is why you should create your category method with your own name. And you can't use compiler directive macros because they work at compile time, not runtime.

```
- (BOOL)myContainsString:(NSString*)substring 
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(containsString:)]) {
        return [self containsString:substring];
    } else {
        return [self rangeOfString:substring].location != NSNotFound;
    }
}
```

Now you use `[someString myContainsString:someSubstring]` in all of your code.

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote? No one learns unless you explain the problem.

Comment: I did not do the downvote, but I presume the downvoter thought that you did not fulfill my first condition of not having to juggle between `{prefix}ContainsString` and `containsString`.